# Hardy Weinberg Explanation

Tags: evolution, hardy-weinberg

I am able to calculate frequencies for allele and genotype, but I don't understand how to tell if the population is at equilibrium. Or how to determine how many generations of random mating would be needed to reach HW equilibrium. I thought the proportions didn't change from generation to generation?

number of individuals: TT-200, Tc-200, cc-600
observed frequencies : TT-0.2, Tc-0.2, cc-0.6
HW frequencies       : TT-0.05, Tc-0.35, cc-0.60

p=.33, q=.77

Answer (score 1):

The answer is logical if you understand the reasoning behind Hardy-Weinberg. I recommend that you to have a look at the post [Solving Hardy Weinberg problems](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/58205/solving-hardy-weinberg-problems) and try to answer the question yourself. Once you've done that, you can hover over the yellow zone below for the answer to compare against what you've understood.

The answer:

> If the assumptions of Hardy-Weinberg are respected (see [Assumptions of Hardy-Weinberg rule](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/58534/assumptions-of-hardy-weinberg-rule)), incl. random mating, then a population is back to Hardy-Weinberg equilibrium at the beginning of any single generation. H-W equilibrium is directly caused by the random sampling of gametes. This random sampling is happening at every single generation and therefore a single generation is enough to get back to H-W equilibrium.