# Hardy-Weinberg sex linked formula

Tags: genetics, evolution, sexual-reproduction, allele, hardy-weinberg

The "big five" assumptions are the ones listed in the main text. However, the basic formulation of Hardy-Weinberg equilibrium also relies on a few other assumptions;

Allele and genotype frequencies don't differ between males and females. That is, the basic form of Hardy-Weinberg does not cover sex-linked genes.

so, is there a modified formula?

Comment: What "main text" are you referring to?

Comment: Also, exactly what is your question (modified formula of what?)? Is it on how to calculate genotypic frequencies in the presence of sex-linkage, or on how sex-linkage affects the HW-equilibrium?

Answer (score 2):

**Solving Hardy-Weinberg problems**

First of all, you might want to have a look at the post

- [Solving Hardy-Weinberg problems](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/58205/solving-hardy-weinberg-problems)

and eventually at

- [Assumptions of Hardy-Weinberg rule](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/58534/assumptions-of-hardy-weinberg-rule)

After reading the first post, you should be able to answer your question yourself. I encourage you to try it before reading what follows.

**Hardy-Weinberg for sex-linked loci**

I will make an example. Let's consider a case where males are `XY` and females `XX` (like in mammals for example). Let `A` and `B` be two alleles of a bi-allelic present on the `X` chromosome. The frequency of these two alleles in the entire population are $p$ and $q$. Let's assume the locus is present on the `X` chromosome. We will assume that the allele frequency do not differ between males and females.

In males, there are two possible genotypes. `A` and `B`. Their frequency among males are noted $f_{m,A}$ and $f_{m,B}$ are

$$f_{m,A} = p$$

$$f_{m,B} = q$$

In females, there are three possible genotypes. `AA`, `AB` (or `BA`) and `BB`. Their frequency among females are noted $f_{f,AA}$, $f_{f,AB}$ and $f_{f,BB}$ and are

$$f_{f,AA} = p^2$$
$$f_{f,AB} = 2pq$$
$$f_{f,BB} = q^2$$

If the sex ratio (the ratio of the number of males over the number of females) is $r$, then the genotypes frequencies in the overall population are the ones from above multiplied by $r$ and $1-r$ for males and females, respectively.